# Upload files to SharePoint Online using Azure Logic Apps

Tags: sharepoint-online, azure, logic-app

I'm creating a Logic App to copy pdf files from a URL like `https://somedomain.com/somefolder/FileToCopy.pdf` to a document library in SharePoint Online.

My problem is that I don't know which action to use. Since the source file is outside SharePoint, I can't use any SharePoint actions.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a connection to SharePoint Online in logic app. A connection provides connectivity between a logic app and another service.

We can use the SharePoint Online connector to manage SharePoint lists.

We can use SharePoint online triggers and SharePoint online actions to copy files.

For more detailed information, refer to the article below.

Get started with the SharePoint Online connector.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-create-api-sharepointonline

Comment: I have a connection and a trigger. I can move documents between SharePoint libraries with a "SharePoint Copy File" action, but I can't find an action to copy documents from a location outside SharePoint to a SharePoint library. That's my issue, sorry if it was unclear. Thanks for your effort though.

Comment: I am afraid the files from the location outside sharepoint cannot be copied to sharepoint library through logic app.

Comment: Then I guess my question has been answered.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using the 'Get file content'(Azure File Storage) action.

Pass the source file location to it, then you will be able to pass the 'File Content' variable from that action, into your 'Create file' (SharePoint) action.

[image]